How can I plot a sublevel set?
I wish to create a 2d plot which includes the sublevel set of a two variable function. The plot would also include other single variable functions. I am able to plot the region from a saved splot of the two variable function as points, but I have not been able to figure out how to just have the sublevel set as a shaded region. Thank you for any suggestions.
set table 'sublevel.dat'
splot f(x,y)
unset table

plot g(x), sublevel.dat using 1:($3\< value ? $2 : 1/0)

with points # works but not really just shading
or
with filledcurves (various other stuff none satisfactory)
or
set table 'sublevel.dat'
set contour ; set cntrparam levels discrete value
unset surface ; set view map
splot f(x,y)
unset table

plot g(x), sublevel.dat using 1:($3\< value ? $2 : 1/0)

with filledcurves xy=clever_x,clever_y # sometimes works but definitely not always

Could you please give a minimal (working) example such that we can reproduce a plot which comes close to your case? What is f(x,y)? Perhaps provide a graph or handsketch to illustrate what you want.

What does "... sometimes works but definitely not always" mean? Do you maybe want to get a certain contour level filled? Please give a concrete example of f(x,y).

The function is (2uyxd − (uxdy + uydx))^2 − 4(uxxd − uxdx)(uyyd − uydy), where d(x,y)=xu_x(x,y)+yu_y(x,y) and u(x,y) is (numerically) determined by

The function is  $f(x,y)=4(u_{xx} d-u_xd_x)(u_{yy} d-u_yd_y)- \big(2u_{xy} d -(u_xd_y+u_yd_x)\big)^2 $, where $d(x,y)=xu_x(x,y)+yu_y(x,y)$ and $u(x,y)$ is (numerically) implicitly determined by $y = u+\frac{1-u}{2}\Big(\sqrt{\big(x-\sqrt{1-u^2}\big)^2+\frac{1}{81}}
-\frac{1}{9}\Big)$. The bounding contour $f(x,y)=0$ is not so nice, making it hard to find  a clever pair $x,y$ which can be used to produce a nicely shaded sublevel set. A related function. $f_1(x,y)=1/x-\frac{u_xu_{yy}-u_{xy}u_y}{u_y^2}$ does have a nice bounding contour and clever $(x,y)$'s are not hard to find.

I was hoping I had just overlooked a standard way of producing evenly shade sublevel sets.

Thanks for the details, however, so far, I don't even know how I could plot this function with gnuplot. What is e.g. u_xx, u_yy and u_xy, etc. ? Could you maybe show in a gnuplot script and graph how this function actually looks like?

The following probably doesn't fully answer your exact question, but maybe helps to find a solution.
If you want to fill a contour line up to (or from) a certain level you could simply set the color palette accordingly, e.g.
set palette defined (zmin c1, z0 c1, z0 c0, zmax c0)

where zmin, zmax, z0 are the minimum, maximum and desired level and c0 and c1 the desired colors.
First you plot your function into a table using set contour and set cntrparam level discrete z0 which will put the z-data into the first block (index 0) and the contour line(s) in following blocks (here: just one contour line in index 1). Plot this data ... index 0 with image and ... index 1 with lines.
When using a function, the higher you set samples and isosamples (here: 250), the more precise/smoother the border will get, but it takes longer.
Although I don't know how to plot your special function, but if you have your data already in a file or table   x   y   z=f(x,y), you could use the same procedure.
Script:
### fill contour above/below certain level
reset session

f(x,y) = sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x)

z0 = 0
set contour
set cntrparam levels discrete z0
set table $Data
    set samples    250
    set isosamples 250
    splot sample [x=-7:7][y=-7:7] '++' u 1:2:(f(x,y))
unset table
stats $Data u 3 nooutput   # get zmin,zmax
zmin = STATS_min
zmax = STATS_max
set xrange noextend
set yrange noextend
set tics out
set key out noautotitle
set cbrange[zmin:zmax]
set style fill solid border lt -1
unset colorbox

c0 = "0xffffff"   # fillcolor 0
c1 = "0xffcccc"   # fillcolor 1
set palette defined (zmin c1, z0 c1, z0 c0, zmax c0)

plot $Data index 0 u 1:2:3 w image, \
        keyentry w boxes fc rgb c1 ti "z < ".z0, \
        '' index 1 u 1:2 w l lc "black" ti "z = ".z0, \
        keyentry w boxes fc rgb c0 ti "z > ".z0
### end of script

Result: (output from wxt terminal)

Addition: (transparent "fill")
As far as I know, you cannot set a transparent fillcolor (at least not in gnuplot 5.4), but you can use the ternary operator (check help ternary) and set the values z>0 to NaN. If you then use, e.g. the terminal pngcairo with option transparent you will get a PNG with transparent areas and background.
You need to change the first plotting line to
plot $Data index 0 u 1:2:($3>z0 ? NaN : $3) w image

and add the following lines at the end:
set term pngcairo transparent
set output "SO79103168.png"
    replot
set output

Output: (Screenshot of generated PNG imported into Inkscape with checkerboard background)


Thank you very much! I will try it. I especially like the use of sample and the defined palette. If possible, I will  modify it so that the fill is transparent, or at least no fill when f>z0.

Building upon the solution, here is another way which uses rgbalpha. It does not provide the boundary. (I tried and failed to use watchpoints.) If the color c1 is set to fully transparent nothing appears.
### fill contour above/below certain level
reset session

f(x,y) = sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x)

z0 = 0
set tics out
set key out noautotitle

# rgbalpha does not seem to like quotes
c0 = 0xffffffff   # fillcolor 0
c1 = 0x77ffcccc   # fillcolor 1

set urange [-7:7] ; set vrange [-7:7]

set samples 1000,1000
set isosamples 300,300
plot [-7:7][-7:7] for [n=-3:3] f(x,2*n) +2*n ,\
'++'  u 1:2:(f($1,$2)>z0 ? c0 : c1 ) with rgbalpha, \
        keyentry w boxes fc rgb c1 ti "z < ".z0   
### end of script

